# Issues in data loading into Spark from Json dumped from dynamo db to s3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb

I need help in parsing this data into Spark Dataframe.json

the structure of the json file is as below :

```
"categories": {
    "M": {
      "schoolHash": {
        "N": "0.27235612"
      },
      "audioBooksHash": {
        "N": "0.7517752"
      },
      "contk": {
        "N": "0.48212662"
      }
    }
}
```

and what I have done is as below

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("categories", MapType(StringType, ArrayType(MapType(StringType, DoubleType))),
        true),
      StructField("nextRequestAt", StringType, true),
      StructField("requestId", StringType, true),
      StructField("requestedAt", StringType, true),
      StructField("status", StringType, true),
      StructField("url", StringType, true),
      StructField("validUntil", StringType, true)


    ))
    val df = spark.read.option("multiLine", true)
        .schema(schema)
        .json(s"${PATH}/*-load-dynamodb-data.json")
```

O/p is -> categories = null

```
+----------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|categories|nextRequestAt        |requestId|requestedAt          |status|url                                                                                                                                     |validUntil           |
+----------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|null      |{"N":"1631595262"}   |null     |{"N":"1629003261857"}|null  |{"http://abc"}                                                                                                                          |{"N":"1636779262"}   |
|null      |{"N":"1599037109070"}|null     |{"N":"1588669021526"}|null  |{"S":"http://16k"}                                                                                                                      |{"N":"1591261022000"}|
+----------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

Other cols are loaded properly as its simple,

FYI, this data is dumped from dynamoDB

Any help will be really good . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `categories` struct has an `ArrayType` and the JSON example you've provided doesn't contain any lists, it contains only dicts i.e. `MapType`.

Here's an example of `categories` struct:

```py
data = [
    {
        "categories": {
            "M": {
                "schoolHash": {"N": "0.27235612"},
                "audioBooksHash": {"N": "0.7517752"},
                "contk": {"N": "0.48212662"},
            }
        }
    }
]
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField(
            "categories",
            MapType(
                StringType(),
                MapType(
                    StringType(),
                    MapType(
                        StringType(),
                        StringType(),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )
    ]
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- categories: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Dataframe:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|categories                                                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{M -> {schoolHash -> {N -> 0.27235612}, contk -> {N -> 0.48212662}, audioBooksHash -> {N -> 0.7517752}}}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Please note that numbers in the JSON are strings, so you can't use `DoubleType` in the schema. I guess you'll have to cast all of them to `DoubleType` after `explode`. Another way (if it's possible) is to preprocess JSON records before loading them to Dataframe.

Comment: thanks @Vlad Siv

Comment: @SumanBanerjee You're welcome! If this answers your question, please mark it as answered.